# build regexp in lisp

Tags: regular-expressions

Is there a package that provides a clearer syntax for building complicated regexes in code?

I currently have in my `.emacs` this regex, which matches various Java package names:

```
"\\(com\\.example\\|net\\|jahuwaldt\\.plot\\|javax\\.swing\\|java\\.\\(awt\\|util\\)\\|org\\.apache\\)\\.[a-z0-9_.]*"
```

With all the backslashes and parentheses, I think it does what I intend.  If I could do something like

```
(require '?)

(let ((re
        (?-expr
           (?-or (?-literal "com.example")
              (?-literal "net.jahuwaldt.plot")
              (?-literal "javax.swing")
              (?-expr (?-literal "java.") (?-or "awt" "util"))
              (?-literal "org.apache"))
           (?-literal ".")
           (?-repeated (?-group "a-z0-9_.")))
```

that would be a lot clearer to read and edit.  And I wouldn't worry that when I add a new value that I was putting it in at the wrong place.

Is there a package that more or less does what my invented `?` package does here?

I expect this to be slower than putting the actual regex in, but I usually have this in interactive commands, where I wouldn't notice the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the structured `rx` notation. [Link to the Emacs manual on rx](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rx-Notation.html)